# Connection between symmetric functions and characters of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In Richard Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics*, Vol. 2, the following is an exercise:

> Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Show that $\sum_{w\in S_n}{p_{\rho(w^k)}}$ is a nonnegative integer linear combination of Schur functions. Equivalently, the function $r_k=r_{n,k} : S_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $r_k(w)=~\#\{u\in S_n : u^k = w\}$ is a character of $S_n$.

I do not understand how these statements are equivalent.

Comment: What is $\rho(w^k)$? In any case, you want the relationship between Schur functions and characters of the symmetric group described in Definition 2 here: http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/11/15/the-many-faces-of-schur-functions/

Comment: Thank you! The link is very helpful. If $w\in S_n$, then the \textit{cycle type} $\rho(w)$ is the partition $$\rho(w)=(\rho_1, \rho_2, ...) \vdash n$$ such that the cycle lengths of w (in its factorization into disjoint cycles) are $\rho_1, \rho_2, \ldots$.